# Dynamically add image to a slider in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. Basically implemented a slider which works perfectly. Now **Main thing is that I want the images that I used to be uploaded by admin user**. I don't have idea to achieve this. Please help me. Amy help is heartly appreciated.

Here is my code :-

```
<aside class="portfolio-right">
  <ul class="mybxslider">
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/acc-thumbnail-1.jpg" /></li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/acc-thumbnail-2.jpg" /></li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/acc-thumbnail-3.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
 <script>
    $('.mybxslider').bxSlider({
          adaptiveHeight: true,
          mode: 'fade'
     });
 </script>
</aside>
```

Comment: You can use [`Advanced Custom Fields`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to save the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom post type `Slider Images` & add slider image as feature image in that post type..

for display that images in slider use

```
<ul class="mybxslider">
<?php
$args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'slider_post', //Post type
            'posts_per_page' => 10                     
            );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();

    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>
    <li><img src="<?=$url?>" width="350" height="350" /></li>
<?php } } ?>
</ul>
```